# Modern look for Netbeans Jframe

Tags: user-interface

I need create an GUI for a school project on Netbeans however the drag and drop opetions just feel to outdated is there anyway to get a more modern look with more options?

I have created a GUI but i want it to look more like the apps we use on a day to day basis